# DBSCAN or HDBSCAN is better option? and why?

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, hdbscan

which clustering method is considered to be the best among DBSCAN and HDBSCAN and what is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 6):

The main disavantage of **DBSCAN is that is much more prone to noise**, which may lead to false clustering. On the other hand, **HDBSCAN focus on high density** clustering, which reduces this noise clustering problem and allows a **hierarchical clustering** based on a decision tree approach.

For a head to head comparison between DBSCAN and HDBSCAN: [DBSCAN / HDBSCAN Clustering](https://dinhanhthi.com/dbscan-hdbscan-clustering/)

For an explanation of many clustering methods until HDBSCAN you can check here: [Comparing Python Clustering Algorithms](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html)